# Link back to the resolved case in MS Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using an on-premise installation of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013.

I have an issue about the Cases section.

The Case entity allows users to track issues and work on them through resolution BUT when a user closes a case she cannot see those “resolution” activities in the Accounts activities list.

Can you suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The default activities shows a filtered view of **Open** Activities. If you wanna find your "resolution" activities, you could use the "Closed Activities" view, or, you can always use an advanced find to filter activities whose Activity Type is Case Resolution and Status is Closed, with, optionally, the Regarding being your case, for example.

If what you really want is knowing how a case was resolved, might be good looking at the "Find resolution to similar cases" section [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-and-manage-a-case.aspx) to link resolutions to other cases.

Cheers from [DynamicsValue](http://dynamicsvalue.com)